# Windows Phone not taking screenshot completely

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I've have a task in WP8

I need to Take a Screenshot and Send to Some Server when User Tap (A button or so?) in WP8 Screen

I am sending it successfully But Problem is sometimes it's not sending the whole screen to my server

Here is my code:

```
private void LayoutRoot_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        TakeScreenShort();

    }  private void TakeScreenShort()
    {
        WriteableBitmap bmpCurrentScreenImage = new WriteableBitmap((int)this.ActualWidth, (int)this.ActualHeight);
        bmpCurrentScreenImage.Render(LayoutRoot, new MatrixTransform());
        bmpCurrentScreenImage.Invalidate();
        byte[] bytearray = null;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            WriteableBitmap wbitmp = new WriteableBitmap(bmpCurrentScreenImage);
            wbitmp.SaveJpeg(ms, wbitmp.PixelWidth, wbitmp.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
            ms.Seek(100, SeekOrigin.Current);
            bytearray = ms.GetBuffer();
        }
        string str = Convert.ToBase64String(bytearray);
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
        {
            id = 11544714,
            img = str,
            width = bmpCurrentScreenImage.PixelWidth,
            height = bmpCurrentScreenImage.PixelHeight,

        });

        string url = "http://178.188.9.96/imageservice/image.php";
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
        webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        webClient.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(proxy_UploadStringCompleted);
        webClient.UploadStringAsync(new Uri(url), "POST", json, null);

    }

    private void proxy_UploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var response = e.Result;
        var jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response);
    }
```

Sometimes it's taking fullscreen and sometimes it's not taking the whole screen.

Comment: not sure about this, but i think telerik has some form of this already implemented for it's error reports.  Somehow you can email an base 64 string in the error report, and then use a website to view the screenshot.  Maybe there is a helper method there for you?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can't get screenshot programatically.
Weirdly, you have managed this to work, you should just get several (3 or so) to make sure to get all.